# How to solve decimal.InvalidOperation on the server?

Tags: python, django, docker, decimal

**Info:** I have a project where frontend is on ReactJS, and backend is on Django.

**The problem:** When customer placing an order, the server returns 500 InvalidOperation at /api/orders/ [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

**Additional info:** It works perfect on test server, but fails on live. The docker containers and back/front code are the same.

**Taken efforts:** rows like

```
round(Decimal((obj.total_price * 100)) / discount_revers - Decimal(obj.total_price), 2)
```

i transform into

```
round(((Decimal(obj.total_price) * Decimal(100))) / discount_revers - Decimal(obj.total_price), 2)
```

and the error still the same.

**The Question:** How to solve this?

Comment: Your given code is not enough to reproduce the problem. Please add the _full_ error traceback and a [mre] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`(Decimal(obj.total_price) * Decimal(100))` result in a `decimal.Decimal` and `discount_reverse` is (probably) a float.

You cannot calculate with these types. They both need to be either `decimal.Decimal` or `float`.

---

Change `discount_reverse` to `Decimal(discount_reverse)` and it should work.

Comment: Still the same error on live server and no error on test server

Comment: Could you maybe split up the calculation and test each operation to see exactly where the error occurs? That would be helpful. I'm also quit confused on why it works on the test server. Are both the same python version?